# How do get the social login prompt to display in a popup?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using the socialite package to implement social login in my project. I am able display a popup to prompt the user to login in using one of the social networking sites and I am able to successfully login the user based on what they select.

My problem is that the prompt by the social networking site asking the user to all my app access to their profile happens on the main page itself, I would like to have this happen on a popup but not able to figure out how to do this.

I should say that I am a total noob at this, my first site and any help regarding this would be awesome.

Comment: you cant do it php only.. you need javascript

Comment: doesn't socialite handle all of the authentication logic, where would i use javascript to launch a popup?

Comment: you said it right socialite handle all of the authentication logic, but showing popup has nothing to do with authentication logic

Comment: maybe i should have started off with saying i am total noob at this. Can you give a little more direction that just using javascript?